# Apache and Ngnix configuration files are replaced upon patching

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, configuration, update

I am using Apache and Ngnix on a CentOS 6.x machine. I run into the problem that when patching either of these services using `yum update`, default configuration files are rewritten into the corresponding configuration directories (`/etc/httpd/{conf,conf.d}` for Apache, and `/etc/nginx` and `/etc/nginx/conf.d` for Nginx), overriding the changes to configuration that I have intentionally made.

The only non-standard part of the configuration for the web servers I can think of is I have removed configuration files:

- Apache `etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`
- Nginx `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

and replaced them with other configuration files with different names. After updating, these files reappear, and unsurprisingly there are conflicts in the configuration at that point.

Is there a way to avoid this so I do not need to constantly recheck the contents of the configuration directories? Or do I just need to put up with this nuisance and recheck the configuration upon patching every time?

Comment: This is not the default behaviour.  What has been changed, or is non-standard, about the system as it is currently configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, RH updates will create files if they don't exist, but won't overwrite them if they do.

On my servers, if I want not to use a default file, instead of removing it I truncate it to zero length, and updates then don't touch it:

```
[me@lory ~]$ ls -la /etc/httpd/conf.d/
[...]
-r--r--r--. 1 root root        0 May 31  2009 wordpress.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      491 Feb 12  2013 wordpress.conf.rpmnew
```

If you want to be particularly kind to yourself, you could leave a comment in the file saying why you aren't using it, and pointing to the file where you *do* keep your config instead.